# Python Error: Can't convert complex to float

Tags: python

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

def integrand(y,a):

    x = ((1-((0.0001303290910*y**2)/0.9520444748+a*y))*(1/0.0002017404542))**(0.5)

    return float(x)

a = 0.005

volume = quad(integrand,-70,110,args=(a))

print(volume)
```

I keep getting the same error no matter what I do, and I can't seem to find the issue.

```
Here is my error

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-23-42d96b8cb524> in <module>()
      9 a = 0.005
     10 
---> 11 volume = quad(integrand,-70,110,args=(a))
     12 
     13 print(volume)


~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst)
    339     if weight is None:
    340         retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
--> 341                        points)
    342     else:
    343         retval = _quad_weight(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py in
_quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points)
    446     if points is None:
    447         if infbounds == 0:
--> 448             return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    449         else:
    450             return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

TypeError: can't convert complex to float
```

Comment: Please include the whole error message (including the traceback) in your post.

Comment: you are not passing parameters into `integrand` function

Comment: I've included the entire error message

Answer (score 0):

That's actually more of a math problem than a Python one. You're trying to compute the square root of potentially negative numbers. Python's `a ** b` returns a `float` if `a` is positive, but returns a `complex` number if it's negative:

```
In [28]: (-1) ** 0.5
Out[28]: (6.123233995736766e-17+1j)
```

Complex numbers cannot be converted to floats easily, and that's the error you're seeing.

It's difficult to suggest a fix for this problem without knowing the exact application. If the values should all be positive, you probably have a bug in your formula. If not, you have to rethink if what you're trying to do is mathematically correct.

Does that help?

Comment: 0.0002017404542x^2+(0.0001303290910y^2)/(0.9520444748+αy)=1, is the the cross section of the object that I need to find the volume for. In order to find the volume, im pretty sure that this function needs to be integrated. As a result, I solved for x and that is what I have in my code above. Hopefully that explains a little bit of what I am attempting to do.